# Spacing Issue Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

write a report in Crystal however I cannot seem to get rid of the spacing before and between lines for the field "DetCommentDescript". I have supressed the field, placed the field in a textbox and tried to supress it however nothing seems to work.

The following shows the layout of the report and the output in which I have highlighted the spaces.

[image]

The report should look like the following:

[image]

I have not used any formulas or groups, etc. I have supressed if blank in sections but am not getting any luck.

Does anyone have any ideas, clues or recommendations?

Thanks.

Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding another detail section for the offending field:

[image]

Then I did the following in section expert for the new section:

[image]

Finally:

[image]